# Terraform how to pass .tfvars file to module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I've got a project I've broken into the following directory structure

```
main.tf

lambda-vars/
- terraform.tfvars

.terraform/
- Modules/ 
--Lambda/
---main.tf
---variables.tf
```

In `main.tf` i want to pass, the tfvars file to the `.terraform/Modules/Lambda/variables.tf` file

The `variables.tf` file is set up like this where it can take the variables defined in the `terraform.tfvars`

```
variable "lambda_name" {
  type = string
  description = "lambda_name"
}

variable "s3_bucket_name" {
  type = string
  description = "s3_bucke_name"
}
```

and the `.tfavrs` file is set up like

```
//Lambdas Common Variables
s3_bucket_name = "s3_bucket"
lambda_name = "lambda"
```

Where all the variables in .tfvars matches the variables in variables.tf

in the main.tf file i want to define the terraform.tfvars file like this

```
module "lambdas" {
  source = "git::https://*******************/repos/Lambda"
  variables = "./lambda-vars/terraform.tfvars"
}
```

Is there a way i can pass this to the module? Both the `tfvars` and `variables.tf` files are massive (someone else set this up and i dont want to use the CLI to do this) thats why im looking to do it this way.

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you should do?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to pass variables the way you are trying to do it:

```
variables = "./lambda-vars/terraform.tfvars"
```

Instead you have to **explicitly pass** each variable to your module separately:

```
variable "lambda_name" {
  type = string
  description = "lambda_name"
}

variable "s3_bucket_name" {
  type = string
  description = "s3_bucke_name"
}


module "lambdas" {
  source = "git::https://*******************/repos/Lambda"
  s3_bucket_name = var.s3_bucket_name
  lambda_name = var.lambda_name
}
```